# PyProj doesn't reproduce original coordinate when transforming back

Tags: python, coordinate-system, pyproj

Why does PyProj give me a different coordinate to the original when I convert from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:7856 and back again?

```
from pyproj import Proj, Transformer

long, lat = (151.19203152785565, -33.85640955685181 )

transformer = Transformer.from_crs("epsg:4326", 'epsg:7856')
x, y = transformer.transform( lat, long)
transformer = Transformer.from_crs('epsg:7856', "epsg:4326")
new_lat, new_long = transformer.transform( x, y)
print(f"long={long}, new_long={new_long}, lat={lat}, new_lat={new_lat}")

>>> long=151.19203152785565, new_long=151.19203696179443, lat=-33.85640955685181, new_lat=-33.85639687288564
```

It's just over a meter misplaced, but enough of a difference to not be a rounding error.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce. Here is the whole test:

```
C:\OSGeo4W>python
Python 3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from pyproj import Proj, Transformer
>>> long, lat = (151.19203152785565, -33.85640955685181 )
>>> transformer = Transformer.from_crs("epsg:4326", 'epsg:7856')
>>> x, y = transformer.transform( lat, long)
>>> print(x)
332747.46615825826
>>> print(y)
6252295.879809214
>>> transformer = Transformer.from_crs('epsg:7856', "epsg:4326")
>>> new_lat, new_long = transformer.transform( x, y)
>>> print(f"long={long}, new_long={new_long}, lat={lat}, new_lat={new_lat}")
long=151.19203152785565, new_long=151.19203152785565, lat=-33.85640955685181, new_lat=-33.85640955685181
```

Pyproj versions:

```
pyproj info:
    pyproj: 3.2.1
      PROJ: 8.2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, that helped me figure it out. It's a bug that existed in PROJ (not pyproj) version 8.0.1. I don't know if it existed in other versions of PROJ. The bug is in the PROJ binaries and not the database.

Upgrading PROJ resolves it - if using Anaconda like I was the only way to do this is to throw away the environment and recreate it fresh with the required modules, trying to uninstall, reinstall, or force any change to PROJ through Anaconda just confuses its dependency management horribly, and as far as I could tell it doesn't facilitate replacing a PROJ install that is already referenced by other modules.